# How to access list data in Sharepoint from an external application?

Tags: 2010, list

My apologies if this question is already asked but I did not find similar questions.

There is an intranet Sharepoint site which cannot be accessed externally. I have an external application which has nothing to do with Sharepoint. I want to access the data in the Sharepoint list and store it in my applications database. I want to poll the Sharepoint list so that the data is in sync. How can I go about doing this? I am new to Sharepoint development so I am looking for the correct route to take to do something like this.

The Sharepoint version is 2010 SP2. What about 2013 version? Would I need a different approach. I have managed to access data from Sharepoint-Online but the sharepoint intranet seem to be a whole different beast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

- Create an application/web service that resides on web accessible server. Let it receive the external requests and fetch the data from the SharePoint list.
- Host your application, or a web service, in Azure and use one of several techniques to connect to on-prem services. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/
- Create an on-prem application that polls the SharePoint list and pushes the data out to a cloud service where your application can pick it up.
- Create a scheduled PowerShell script that runs on the SharePoint server and pushes the data to a cloud service.
- Create a scheduled PowerShell script that runs on the SharePoint server, periodically dumps the list to CSV, JSON or other format, and then uploads it to OneDrive or other service where your application can pick it up.

All of the above require an on-site setup with proper permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am leaning towards writing a PowerShell script or building an application that can be installed in the Sharepoint Server. Looking around I see a lot of solutions written in C#. Is that because it is easier with C#? Can I use applications written in other languages? Are there any tried and tested solutions out there for this purpose. All I can find is bits and pieces of information which usually seem to be vague. Are there any preferred solution from Microsoft